# Grunt: is it possible to run task with any keyboard?

Tags: gruntjs

using watch in grunt you change something in js or css and grunt execute task to build uglified file.

My problem is that when I save it is too long time uglifing. It works fine but I would love to optimize it . One way I thout it is to execute grunt when I push Ctrl + Shift + B or when we execute F5.

My directory structure

My project

```
   ...
    Scripts
        Dependencies
            ...
        Lib
        app.js
```

My gruntfile code is:

```
module.exports = function ( grunt )
{
    grunt.initConfig( {
        uglify: {
            ecma: {
                files: {
                    'test.min.js': ['Scripts/**/*.js', '!Scripts/Dependencies/angularjs/i18n/**/*.js']
                }
            }
        },
        cssmin: {  //minificado css
            minify: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'css/',
                src: ['css/**/*.css', '!css/*.min.css'],
                dest: 'css/',
                ext: 'test.min.css'
            }
        },
        watch: { 
            styles: {
                files: ["Scripts/**/*.js", "css/**/*.css"],
                tasks: ["cssmin:minify", "uglify:ecma"],
                options: { spawn: false }
            }
        }

    } );

    grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-uglify' );
    grunt.loadNpmTasks( "grunt-contrib-cssmin" );
    grunt.loadNpmTasks( "grunt-contrib-watch" );
```

ejecuta por orden los siguientes plugins.
        grunt.registerTask( 'default', ['uglify', 'cssmin', 'watch'] );
    };

I was trying to exlude angular culture.

Which library of grunt can I use to detected the keyboard?